# Pass a computed property to css url() with v-bind in Vue 3

Tags: html, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I' trying to pass a computed property value to a url() in css using v-bind with Vue 3 and Nuxt:

```
<template>
  <div class="box-container"></div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>

const props = defineProps ( {
  maskImage:  { type: String, default: ''},
  width:      { type: Number, default: 100 }
})


const width = computed(()=> props.width + 'px')
const maskImage = computed(() => `assets/sprite/svg/${props.maskImage}.svg`)

</script>


<style lang="sass" scoped>

.box-container
  background-color: blue
  width: v-bind(width)
  -webkit-mask-image: url(v-bind(maskImage))
  -webkit-mask-position: center
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat
</style>
```

With this code, the computed width is working right, but the mask url isn't. In the inspector I can see that a kind hashed value is seted in mask-image:  `-webkit-mask-image: url(var(--20ff1bb8-maskImage))`

How can I pass the value in the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a css variable with `url()`, you need to specify this function when defining:

```js
const maskImage = computed(() => 'url(https://mdn.github.io/css-examples/masking/star.svg)');
```

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: ¡Thanks! The kind of answer that makes understand many things.